# Question Regarding Probability (Drownings per Population Size)

Tags: probability

The Question:

> According to the National Safety Council, the average number of
>   drownings in the United States is 2.7 per 100,000 population. What is
>   the probability that your city of 250,000 will experience more than
>   two drownings this year?

My solution:

[image]

Comment: The usual difficulty with problems like this is to sort out what assumptions you are meant to make.  Path of least resistance is to assume that each individual has an independent probability of drowning equal to $\frac {2.5}{100000}$.  This isn't realistic, of course...the probability of drowning in Phoenix is, presumably, lower than the probability of drowning in Homer Alaska.  Whatever assumption you are making, though, you should state it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The $6.75$ you calculated is the *expected* number of drownings for that city of $250,000$ ... it's not the probability of anything.

And multipyling this by $\frac{2.7}{2.0}$ is meaningless ...

What you need to do is to calculate the probability of having $0$ or $1$ drownings, and subtract that from $1$

This is all assuming that every person everywhere has the same probability of drowning ... which is completely unrealistic, but hey ...